# Multi-part numbers and units in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I'm trying to type set something like this "4 x 5 x 6 mm^2". The following command using the `siunitx` package does not generate what I want:

```
\SI{4 x 5 x 6}{mm^3}
```

Instead, it produces “4 mm^3 x 5 mm^3 x 6 mm^3". How do we correct this?

Comment: It's because `4 x 5 x 6 mm^2` is not a standard notation and has ambiguous meaning.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 17):

You are looking for the `product-units` option. It accepts one of five options. Their result is shown in the code sample.

### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}\noindent
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \texttt{repeat} (default) & \SI[product-units=repeat]        {4 x 5 x 6}{mm}   \\
    \texttt{single}           & \SI[product-units=single]        {4 x 5 x 6}{mm^3} \\
    \texttt{power}            & \SI[product-units=power]         {4 x 5 x 6}{mm}   \\
    \texttt{brackets}         & \SI[product-units=brackets]      {4 x 5 x 6}{mm^3} \\
    \texttt{brackets-power}   & \SI[product-units=brackets-power]{4 x 5 x 6}{mm}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This does not work anymore (well, it did not work for me): see the solution to this problem in the post by Mico in [product-units mode with siunitx package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628813/product-units-mode-with-siunitx-package).

To be more precise, you should write either `\qtyproduct[product-units=power]{4 x 5 x 6}{\milli\meter}` or
`\qtyproduct[product-units=single]{4 x 5 x 6}{mm^3}`. But if the squared mm in your question is not a bug you must write
`\qtyproduct[product-units=single]{4 x 5 x 6}{mm^2}`. (Note also that `\qtyproduct[product-units=power]{4 x 5 x 6}{mm}` will NOT work.)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/251402)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.